# How to remove parent DOM node after d3 selection().exit()

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using d3 to create some SVG infographics. On the `selection.enter()` set I'm appending a group (`g`) and within that I'm appending a `path`, which gets animated. On the `exit()` selection I need to animate the `path`, then at the end of the animation, completely remove the parent `g`.

<del>When I say completely remove, I mean to do a `node.parentNode.removeChild(node)` - that is, I don't want to use d3's `remove()` function which just removes it and keeps a reference (as this creates problems with re-adding).</del>

```
var svg = d3svg.selectAll('g').data(myData);
svg.enter().append('g').append('path').attr(...);
svg.exit().select('path')
  .transition()
  .duration(750)
  .attr(...)
  .whatGoesHere()
;
```

So `whatGoesHere` needs to trigger after the `transition()` completes on the `path` and remove the parent `g` object completely.

I have accomplished this using:

```
.each('end', function() {
  this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode); });
```

But it feels like there ought to be a d3 way to get 'back' from a selection to the parent selection, from a `transition` object called on a child? Perhaps I could `var byebye = svg.exit()`, then do the `select('path')` with the transition, then do something with the `byebye` selection of parent groups, but then how to get that to wait for the transitions on the children?

Comment: There's no notion of a "parent selection", so the way you're doing it at the moment is probably the way to do it. I don't understand what you mean when you say that D3 keeps a reference to removed elements -- it doesn't. Could you explain how `.remove()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yeah, I was wrong about that, thanks. I've edited the question in response to your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Put the transition on the parent:

```
var svg = d3svg.selectAll('g').data(myData);
svg.enter().append('g').append('path').attr(...);
svg.exit()
  .transition()   // Set up the transition on the parent
  .duration(750)
  .remove()       // Triggers at the end of the transition
  .select('path')
    .attr(...)    // the transition gets applied to children
;
```